# What are the penalties for fitting multiple similar items in EVE Online?

Tags: eve-online

Many ship fittings in EVE Online state in their description something along the lines of:

> Penalty: Using more than one type of this module or similar modules that affect the same attribute on the ship will be penalized.

What is the nature of this penalty? Is it a hard-and-fast mathematical rule? Will using, for example, two of an item be less effective than using one, or is it a case of diminishing returns?

Comment: It's diminishing returns. Can't remember the exact values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the UniWiki on [Stacking Penalty](http://wiki.eveuniversity.org/Stacking_penalty): ( A broken record, I know )

> The Formula
>
> The stacking penalty for module number n is
>   S(n) = 0.5^(((n-1) / 2.22292081) ^2)
>
> The Numbers
>
> 1st mod: 100.0% effectiveness
>
> 2nd mod: 86.9% effectiveness
>
> 3rd mod: 57.1% effectiveness
>
> 4th mod: 28.3% effectiveness
>
> 5th mod: 10.6% effectiveness
>
> 6th mod: 3.0% effectiveness
>
> As is clear, stacking more than 3 or 4 modules or rigs - unless you really have nothing else at all that you could fit there - that affect the same stat is fairly pointless, as your benefit is so tiny.